# Cómo evitar que se muestre un objeto en un Adapter que lleno a través de una base de datos

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tengo un Adapter que lleno a través de una base de datos de Firebase, y lo que intento hacer es que cuando una de las variables (String activo = usuario.getActivo();) que recibo de la base de datos sea igual a "No", entonces el Adapter no muestre este objeto y muestre los que posean la variable igual a "Sí"

Este es mi Adapter

```
public class AdapterLookingService extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterLookingService.EmpresasViewHolder>
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    List<Usuario> usuarios;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    Context context;

    public AdapterLookingService( List<Usuario> usuarios){
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public EmpresasViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapterls_row_recycler, parent, false);
        EmpresasViewHolder holder = new EmpresasViewHolder(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        context = v.getContext();

        return  holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EmpresasViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);

        String activo = usuario.getActivo();

        holder.textviewempresa.setText(usuario.getUsuario());
        holder.textviewciudad.setText(usuario.getDirección());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usuarios.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){this.listener=listener;}

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

    public static class EmpresasViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textviewempresa, textviewciudad;

        public EmpresasViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textviewempresa = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_empresa);
            textviewciudad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_ciudad);
        }

    }

}
```

Aquí agrego el código del Fragment donde integro el Adapter

```
  //ESTO ES PARA EL RecyclerView

                    final AdapterLookingService adapter;

                    recyclerEmpresas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

                    usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

                    adapter = new AdapterLookingService(usuarios);

                    int adaptercantidad = adapter.getItemCount();
                    if (adaptercantidad == 0){
                        txtnoemp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            EmpresaUser = usuarios.get(recyclerEmpresas.getChildAdapterPosition(view))
                                    .getUsuario();

                                TipoAtencionFragment tafragment = new TipoAtencionFragment();

                                bundle.putString("EmpresaUser", EmpresaUser);                           
                                tafragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                FragmentManager FM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                                FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, tafragment);
                                FT.addToBackStack(null);

                                FT.commit();

                            }

                        }
                    });

                    recyclerEmpresas.setAdapter(adapter);

                    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    mDatabase.child("Empresas " + PaÃ­s).child(Ciudad).child(TipodeEmpresa).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if (dataSnapshot == null){
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                return;
                            } else {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            usuarios.removeAll(usuarios);
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                Usuario usuario = snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                                usuarios.add(usuario);

                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                    //ESTO ES PARA EL RecyclerView
```

No se me ocurre cómo no mostrar un objeto del Adapter dependiendo de las variables...

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: muestra el activity o fragment que instancia el Recycleview

Comment: Filtra la lista antes de pasarsela al adapter. Agregando solo los items que tengan el campo "Si" y notificale.

Comment: @Andrespengineer lo resolví con tu primer comentario amigo, donde dabas un ejemplo sobre cómo disminuir la altura del itemView. Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto. Saludos!

Comment: Excelente, pero mi sugerencia es que si siempre vas a ocultar lo que tengan dicha condicion, lo mejor seria no agregar los elementos que tengan esa condicion a la lista. Porque lo de ocultar las vistas es una vez que ya ha sido dibujada, cuando quieres ocultar pocos elementos, sin embargo, si filtras la lista, la aplicacion gastaria menos recursos en la memoria, porque nunca los dibujará.

Comment: @Andrespengineer cómo podría hacer ese filtro y pasar sólo los datos que contengan el "Sí", ya que es cierto lo que dices, con el código que aplique en tu ejemplo ocultare muchos elementos... Lo ideal sería mostrar sólo los que contengan el "Sí" y no ocultar los que contengan el "No"

Comment: @Andrespengineer arriba agregue el código del Fragment donde integro el Adapter, yo creo que ahí en la llamada de la base de datos se podría hacer algún filtro, no?

Comment: Si, justo antes de `usuarios.add(usuario)` pones el `if` de la condicion que quieres, si esa condicion se da, entonces lo agregas. Y ya no tendrias que poner el codigo de ocultar las vistas, porque nunca se cargaran en el adapter.

Comment: Gracias @Andrespengineer, así funciona mucho mejor, ya que no crea la vista del elemento que contiene "No". Funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

leyendo tu codigo, creo que lo quenecesitas es una simple estructura de control que valide la respuesta, asi:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(EmpresasViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);

        String activo = usuario.getActivo();
        if (activo.equalsIgnoreCase('Si')==true) {
            //si entra aqui es por que si es igual ignorando la mayusculas y minusculas
            holder.textviewempresa.setText(usuario.getUsuario());
            holder.textviewciudad.setText(usuario.getDirección());
        }
        else{
            //aqui puede hacer algo en caso de que la respuesta sea NO
        }

    }
```

Espero te sirva y la marques xD, y me cuentas... **ReNiceCode...**